# Writing to the ObjectOutputStream and getting rubbish back

Tags: java

I put a number of objects into the stream, then get byte array out of it and then read everything back. First two pieces of data arrive in good condition, then I get zeroes and then EOF exception. Why?

```
try {
     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
     objectOutputStream.writeObject("abcdef");
     objectOutputStream.writeInt(1);
     objectOutputStream.writeObject(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8});
     objectOutputStream.writeInt(2);
     objectOutputStream.writeObject(new byte[]{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18});
     objectOutputStream.close();


     byte[] original = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(original));

     byte[] b=new byte[8];
     ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(original));
     String s= (String) objectInputStream.readObject(); // works fine
     objectInputStream.readInt(); // works fine

     objectInputStream.read(b); // why it reads zeroes instead of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]?
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
     int length = objectInputStream.readInt(); // EOF unexpectedly reached, why?
     objectInputStream.read(b);
}
catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Exception:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:2775)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readInt(ObjectInputStream.java:949)
```

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that the first issue is that you need to `close()` your `objectOutputStream`. See the [ObjectOutputStream documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) for examples.

Comment: Added close() but it did not change this behavior

Answer (score 3):

As well as closing your buffered stream...

You want to have readInt() for each writeInt() (as you are doing)  You also need to have readObject() for each writeObject().

If you don't read the same way your wrote, you can't expect it to make any sense.

You are doing

```
objectOutputStream.writeObject(new byte[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8});
```

so you need to do

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) objectInputStream.readObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at how `ObjectOutputStream` handles arrays in `writeObject` (specifically, look at  `ObjectOutputStream.writeArray()`. It writes an array marker byte (to know what kind of object is stored), then the array length and then the array elements themselves.

Long story short, you should read it back with `readObject`, not with plain `read` (unless you want to actually parse that stream of bytes yourself, not expecting your bytes to be retrieved as in the original byte array).

`InputStream.read(byte[])` simply gets the raw stream of bytes and writes them in your buffer.

Moreover, the subsequent calls (other than mere `read()`s) are expected to fail because the pointer is not placed at the beginning of a data structure which the deserializer can understand.

Comment: writeArray() is not a public method of ObjectOutputStream (at least in recent versions of Java?): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html